# C++ output align and decimal place holder?

Tags: c++, precision

Hi I got a little question here.

I am doing my C++ homework and the sample output is

```
% cat this.out
  5.00       0.00 
  1.55       4.76 
 -4.05       2.94 
 -4.05      -2.94 
  1.55      -4.76
```

but what I got was

```
% cat test.out
    5       0
    1.55    4.76
    -4.05   2.94
    -4.05   -2.94
    1.55    -4.76
```

And I couldn't figure out how to make my output format looks like that.
One more problem I had in this case is, I want the first line in my output is something like `5.00   0.00`, but it doesn't work even I set `precision(3)`

Here is my code generates the output, please take a look.

```
file.open (filename, fstream :: in | fstream :: trunc);
    if(!file.is_open())
    {
            cerr << "Error opening file " << filename << endl;
            cout << "Exiting..." << endl;
            exit(0);
    }
    for(i = 0 ; i < num; i ++)
    {
            angle = 2 * M_PI * i/num;
            x = rad * cos(angle);
            y = rad * sin(angle);
            file.precision(3);
            // x, y are double
            file << "\t" << x << "\t" << y << endl;
    }
    cout << "finished";
    file.close();
```

Comment: Use `std::fixed` (as well as `precision`) to get the decimal places right.

Comment: @sje397 Hi thank you for your comment, can you make it a little more detailed? I am not sure where to put the `std::fixed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to look up the [*Input/output manipulators*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip) in the Standard library header [`<iomanip>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iomanip).

These are used inline, like:

```
std::cout << "\t" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(z) << x
```

The ones you'll be most interested in are:

- [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed)
- [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)
- [`std::setw`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
file.precision(2);
file << fixed << "\t" << x << "\t" << y << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

As usual, you need to define a manipulator for the specific semantics.
For quick work, I'll often use one along the lines of:

```
class FFmt
{
    int myWidth;
    int myPrecision:
public:
    FFmt( int width, int precision )
        : myWidth( width )
        , myPrecision( precision )
    {
    }
    friend std::ostream& 
    operator<<( std::ostream& dest, FFmt const& format )
    {
        dest.setf( std::ios_base::fixed, std::ios_base::floatfield );
        dest.precision( myPrecision );
        dest.width( myWidth );
        return dest;
    }
};
```

(In my own code, I derive these from a base class which saves the format
state, and restores it at the end of the full expression.)

This is rather generic.  In practice, you'd create several, with names
like `coord` and `angle`, to specify what you're logically outputting.
However, you get the idea.  Having this, you can then write things like:

```
std::cout << FFmt( 6, 2 ) << x << '\t' << FFmt( 6, 2 ) << y << std::endl;
```